# Solution - about userRef

Tags: reactjs

my first participation =).  Here's an example of a study I'm doing, . It's a simple login form, with email and password.

useRef:
useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

useImperativeHandle:
useImperativeHandle customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref. **As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.** useImperativeHandle should be used with forwardRef:

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
```

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useReducer,
  useEffect,
  useContext,
  useRef,
} from "react";

import Card from "../UI/Card/Card";
import classes from "./Login.module.css";
import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";
import AuthContext from "../../store/auth-context";
import Input from "../UI/Input/Input";

const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "USER_INPUT") {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.includes("@") };
  }
  if (action.type === "INPUT_BLUR") {
    return { value: state.value, isValid: state.value.includes("@") };
  }
  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};

const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "USER_INPUT") {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  if (action.type === "INPUT_BLUR") {
    return { value: state.value, isValid: state.value.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};

const Login = () => {
  const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState(false);

  const [emailState, dispatchEmail] = useReducer(emailReducer, {
    value: "",
    isValid: null,
  });

  const [passwordState, dispatchPassword] = useReducer(passwordReducer, {
    value: "",
    isValid: null,
  });

  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { isValid: emailIsValid } = emailState;
  const { isValid: passwordIsValid } = passwordState;

  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
      setFormIsValid(emailIsValid && passwordIsValid);
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(identifier);
    };
  }, [emailIsValid, passwordIsValid]);

// Here is the useEffect to set the value the initial focus of the email input........
  useEffect(() => {
    if (emailInputRef?.current) {
      emailInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // setEnteredEmail(event.target.value);
    dispatchEmail({ type: "USER_INPUT", val: event.target.value });
    // setFormIsValid(
    //   emailState.value.includes("@") && passwordState.value.trim().length > 6
    // );
  };

  const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // setEnteredPassword(event.target.value);
    dispatchPassword({ type: "USER_INPUT", val: event.target.value });
    // setFormIsValid(
    //   passwordState.value.trim().length > 6 && emailState.value.includes("@")
    // );
  };

  const validateEmailHandler = () => {
    // setEmailIsValid(emailState.value.includes("@"));
    dispatchEmail({ type: "INPUT_BLUR" });
  };

  const validatePasswordHandler = () => {
    // setPasswordIsValid(passwordState.value.trim().length > 6);
    dispatchPassword({ type: "INPUT_BLUR" });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (formIsValid) {
      authCtx.onLogin(emailState.value, passwordState.value);
    } else if (!emailIsValid) {
      emailInputRef.current.focus();
    } else {
      passwordInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };
  // Here is the FORM ........
  return (
    <Card className={classes.login}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Input
          ref={emailInputRef}
          label="E-mail"
          type="email"
          id="email"
          onChange={emailChangeHandler}
          onBlur={validateEmailHandler}
          isValid={emailIsValid}
          value={emailState.value}
        />
        <Input
          ref={passwordInputRef}
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
          onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
          onBlur={validatePasswordHandler}
          isValid={passwordIsValid}
          value={passwordState.value}
        />
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button type="submit" className={classes.btn}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

the component Input:

```
// Here is the import useImperativeHandle and useRef from React ........
import React, { useRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import classes from "./Input.module.css";

// Here is the import useImperativeHandle from React, and the REF of inputs ........
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const activate = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      focus: activate,
    };
  });

  return (
    <div
      className={`${classes.control} ${
        props.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
      }`}
    >
      <label htmlFor="email">{props.label}</label>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type={props.type}
        id={props.id}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        onBlur={props.onBlur}
      />
    </div>
  );
});


export default Input;
```

According to the documents itself, it is recommended to use the useImperativeHandle method, what other alternatives would I have?